# Error C2666 Similar Overloadings

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, raytracing

I am developing a ray tracing project. So, I have lots of vector operations. For product operation, I used operator overloading, and faced with a problem. You can see the details below:

These functions are in a header file named `RayMath.h`

```
//GENERAL INLINES
inline Vector operator*( float c, const Vector& v){ return v * c;   } //Func1
inline Vector operator*( const Vector& v1, Vector& v2 ) { return Vector( v1.x * v2.x, v1.y * v2.y, v1.z * v2.z ); } //Func 2
```

If I add `Func 2`, it gives `C2666, more than one operator` for the operations that use `Func1`. If I do not add `Func 2`, I get a `no operator matches` error. Here is the usage example:

These lines are in a `.cpp` file named `Renderer.cpp`

```
Vector R = ray.direction - 2.f * Dot( ray.direction, N ) * N; //Func1 related
color += trace(  Ray( ( intersectionP + R * EPSILON ), R ) ) * sphere->surfaceColor * sphere->reflection; // Func 2 related
```

I would like to thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe you have a constructor `Vector::Vector(float)` ?

Comment: Let me guess - you also have an overload `operator* (const Vector&, float)`, and a non-explicit constructor `Vector::Vector(float)`. Right?

Comment: Yes, I have this `Vector( float xVal ): x( xVal ), y( xVal ), z( xVal ) {}` constructor. Does it cause this problem?

Comment: Wow, removing `Vector( float)` solved the problem. I have no idea this type of constructors can lead this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already discovered that the Vector(float) constructor causes the problem because it provides an implicit conversion from float to vector. As a basic rule, you should always declare one-arg constructors explicit:

```
explicit Vector(float f): x(f), y(f), z(f)
```

Comment: What if `Vector::Vector(float f)` is provided by a 3rdParty library and cannot be changed?

Comment: @zwcloud Then I would file an issue report against the owner to fix it because it is a quality of implementation problem. If there are a lot of these quality problems in a C++ library I would look for alternatives because it will create a lot of problems. If that is not possible I would consider creating a sane wrapper around the library that does not expose anything problematic in headers.